# Whitelisting cloudflare IP Addresses Using cPanel

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel, cloudflare

I recently tried to add Cloudflare cdn service to my wordpress website [www.kashmirproduce.com](http://www.kashmirproduce.com), I added the cloudflare nameservers from my domain dashboard and installed the cloudflare plugin on my Wordpress site. All the necessary steps were done by me. Despite that the website started showing 521 Unknown code. Upon further investigating i realized that i have to add cloudflare ip addresses to ip whitelist through cpanel. I don't have root access so only could do it through .htaccess file. I scoured the internet for the code required to do that.
So this is what i got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login.php(.*)$ [OR]
        RewriteCond%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^173.245.48.0/20$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^103.21.244.0/22$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^103.22.200.0/22$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^103.31.4.0/22$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^141.101.64.0/18$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^108.162.192.0/18$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^190.93.240.0/20$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^188.114.96.0/20$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^197.234.240.0/22$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^198.41.128.0/17$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^162.158.0.0/15$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^104.16.0.0/12$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^172.64.0.0/13$
        RewriteCond%{REMOTE_ADDR} !^131.0.72.0/22$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
    </IfModule>
```

But I just got a 500 Internal Server Error. Then i tried this code:

```
# Apache 2.2: Whitelist Cloudflare IPs
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 173.245.48.0/20
Allow from 103.21.244.0/22
Allow from 103.22.200.0/22
Allow from 103.31.4.0/22
Allow from 141.101.64.0/18
Allow from 108.162.192.0/18
Allow from 190.93.240.0/20
Allow from 188.114.96.0/20
Allow from 197.234.240.0/22
Allow from 198.41.128.0/17
Allow from 162.158.0.0/15
Allow from 104.16.0.0/12
Allow from 172.64.0.0/13
Allow from 131.0.72.0/22
</IfModule>
# Apache 2.4+: Whitelist Cloudflare IPs
<IfModule authz_core_module>
<RequireAll>
Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
Require ip 103.22.200.0/22
Require ip 103.31.4.0/22
Require ip 141.101.64.0/18
Require ip 108.162.192.0/18
Require ip 190.93.240.0/20
Require ip 188.114.96.0/20
Require ip 197.234.240.0/22
Require ip 198.41.128.0/17
Require ip 162.158.0.0/15
Require ip 104.16.0.0/12
Require ip 172.64.0.0/13
Require ip 131.0.72.0/22
</RequireAll>
</IfModule>
```

But this just threw a 403 access forbidden error on my wordpress wp-admin page. Any suggestions what i should do next?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I change cloudflare SSL settings to Flexible. If you want to whitelist cloudflare IPs or any other IPs then contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.